# Gargantuan Soporific Nirvana

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

### Gargantuan Soporific Nirvana

Thou spinning disq with colours brite!
Asq of the masses what is rite.

Didst thou turn it round and answer first?
Great bonging gong has got me cursed.

Guess ye, the worth of common fare;
Great pyramids and upright squares.

I wait with ears for what I crave:
That answer spake, respondent gave.

Hint:

> [Hint](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/gargantuan-soporific-nirvana/66250#comment200131_66250)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be referring to:

> A variety of game shows, and the Game Show Network

Thou spinning disq with colours brite!
Asq of the masses what is rite.

> Wheel of Fortune, and Family Feud

Didst thou turn it round and answer first?
Great bonging gong has got me cursed.

> I don't know the first line, but the second is The Gong Show. *[EDIT: In the comments, [Chowzen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/gargantuan-soporific-nirvana/66342?noredirect=1#comment200373_66342) hinted at answers coming before the questions; the first line is then a reference to Jeopardy! in which answers are given and contestants must respond with questions.]*

Guess ye, the worth of common fare;
Great pyramids and upright squares.

> The Price is Right, The $100,000 Pyramid, and Hollywood Squares

I wait with ears for what I crave:
That answer spake, respondent gave.

> Generally refers to watching game shows and waiting for the contestant to give their answer, correct or not. *[EDIT: [Phylyp](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/gargantuan-soporific-nirvana/66342?noredirect=1#comment200346_66342) points out in comments that this may also mean "waiting for the respondent to give the same answer you thought of. i.e. 'That answer **I** spake'"]*

Connection to Title:

> The title's initials are GSN, which is also the abbreviation for Game Show Network

Connection to Hint:

> Clearly references the Double Jeopardy round from Jeopardy!

Comment: Very nice answer! I think _"I wait with ears for what I crave: That answer spake, respondent gave."_ also refers to you waiting for the respondent to give the same answer you thought of. i.e. "That answer **_I_** spake".

Comment: The third line sounds like answers coming *before* questions ...

Comment: Ah, now I see; I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be

> a riddlish description of the Stack Exchange system.

*Thou spinning disq with colours brite!

Asq of the masses what is rite.*

> The coloured disc could be a voting or favourite button? Asking the masses what is right definitely sounds like **meta**. And the "q" instead of "k" could be a reference to the fact that this is a **Q**&A site (cf. Arqade, the Gaming Stack Exchange, whose name was deliberately constructed to have a Q&A in the middle).

*Didst thou turn it round and answer first?

Great bonging gong has got me cursed.*

> Getting **ninja'd** to an answer by someone else being quicker.

*Guess ye, the worth of common fare;

Great pyramids and upright squares.*

> Pyramids must be the **upvote** button, for guessing the worth of a post. Not sure about squares.

*I wait with ears for what I crave:

That answer spake, respondent gave.*

> When you post a question on Stack Exchange, you await an answer from a respondent.

Comment: ['Fraid not,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Puctc2SjBF4) but a lot of your explanations do seem to fit.

Comment: Guess I just spend too much time here :-)